# I have a JSON Data that I want to use in the paper.JS with Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, paperjs

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PaperScope, Project, Path, Point } from 'paper';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as paper from 'paper';

declare const drawTrack:any;
declare const parseCrossingData:any;
declare const parseSignallingData:any;  
declare const changeTrackColor:any;
declare const drawBulletin:any;
declare const parseTextdisplay:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = 'paperjsdemo';

    @ViewChild('canvasElement') canvasElement: ElementRef;
    scope: PaperScope;
    project: Project;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        drawTrack();
    }
}
```

The above code is my component.ts file.

```html
<div style="background-color: black;">
    <canvas width="1500" height="650" ></canvas>
</div>
```

The above code is my HTML file. I am getting an error in the component. I have JSON data that I want to use and draw some lines using Paper.JS in angular 8.

Comment: What error are you getting in the component?

Comment: Hi Halfer, Please share the error screenshot along with description

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example of how you can use Paper.js in an Angular app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paper

component:

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import paper from "paper";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("canvasElement") canvasElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    paper.setup(this.canvasElement.nativeElement);

    const circle = new paper.Path.Circle({
      center: paper.view.center,
      radius: 50,
      fillColor: "orange"
    });
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<canvas #canvasElement></canvas>
```